# Using Positive Lookahead inside a Positive Lookbehind?

Tags: python, regex

I want to use the positive lookahead inside a positive lookbehind, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried the following: `(?<=Chapter 1(?=Introduction))(.*)(?=Chapter 2)`

Full text:

````
Chapter 1
Introduction

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text

Chapter 2
Introduction

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text```
````

Comment: Lookbehinds tend to be the most restrictive parts of regular expressions; it wouldn't surprise me to find some implementation where they can't contain lookaheads.  Perhaps if you actually mentioned what regex implementation you're using, someone could confirm whether or not it has such a limitation.  But you have a more fundamental problem here: you're checking for `Introduction` *immediately after* `Chapter 1`, when there's actually a newline character between those two chunks of text.

Comment: @Emma  yea i'm trying to get that output

Comment: Why do you need a positive lookahead inside your lookbehind. Just `(?<=Chapter 1.Introduction)` will achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a lookbehind, you could match Chapter 1 until Introduction. Then use a capturing group with a repeating pattern that checks if the line does not start with Chapter 2.

```
^Chapter 1[\r\n]+Introduction[\r\n]+((?:(?!Chapter 2).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `Chapter 1[\r\n]+` Match Chapter 1 and 1+ newlines
  `Introduction[\r\n]+ Match Introduction and 1+ newlines`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!Chapter 2).*` Negative lookahead, check not starting with Chapter 2
    - `(?:\r?\n|$)` Match either a newline or assert the end of the string
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capture group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OjEhDr/1)

If you want the matches for all the chapters you could change the number 1 into `\d+` and the number 2 in `\d`

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/co4YUv/1)